# Problema com NullPointException em JSF e Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Boa tarde! Estou tendo problemas com um formulário xhtml feito em JSF, pois ele não está setando os valores no UsuarioBean, e quando vou executar o metodo cadastro() presente na classe UsuarioBean o eclipse me retorna um erro do tipo NullPointException. Segue o cadastro.xhtml e o UsuarioBean.class:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


<h:form id="cadastro">
 <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
 <h:head>
  <title>KArtHugo PCs</title>
 </h:head>
 <!-- <marquee scrollamount="40">
  <h1 style="font-size: 100px; color: blue; text-align: left;">Monta
   ai comedia</h1>
  <h:graphicImage url="/images/pc.jpg" />
 </marquee> -->
 <h:body>
  <p:panel header="Cadastro">
   <p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="Nome completo: " for="nome" />
    <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.entidade.nome}" required="true"
     id="nome" />
     
    <p:outputLabel value="Username: " for="nick" />
    <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.entidade.username}" required="true"
     id="nick" />

    <p:outputLabel value="Email: " for="email" />
    <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.entidade.email}" id="email"
     required="true" />

    <p:outputLabel value="Senha: " for="password" />
    <p:password required="true" feedback="true"
     value="#{usuarioBean.entidade.password}" id="password" />

    <p:outputLabel value="Confirme a senha: " for="autPass" />
    <p:password required="true" id="autPass"
     value="#{usuarioBean.autPassword}" />

    <p:column>
     <p:commandButton value="Salvar cadastro" id="btnCadastro"
      action="#{usuarioBean.cadastro()}" update="growl" />
    </p:column>
   </p:panelGrid>
  </p:panel>
 </h:body>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Classe UsuarioBean:

```
package beans;
```

@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class UsuarioBean implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private UserService service;

private String autPassword;

private Usuario entidade;

protected Collection<Usuario> entidades;

public UsuarioBean() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    limpar();
}

public void cadastro() {
    entidades = service.getAll();
    boolean pass = false;
    if (!entidade.getPassword().equals(autPassword)) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("ERROR", new FacesMessage("Confira sua senha!"));
    } else {
        pass = true;
    }
    boolean unique = false;
    for (Usuario u : entidades) {
        if (entidade.getEmail().equals(u.getEmail())) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("ERROR", new FacesMessage("Email já cadastrado"));
        } else {
            unique = true;
        }
    }
    if (pass && unique) {
        entidade.setPassword(service.hash(entidade.getPassword()));
        entidade.setGrupo("USER");
        service.save(entidade);
        limpar();
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Sucesso!",
                    new FacesMessage("Usuario " + entidade.getNome() + " cadastrado!"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public String getUserLogin() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    Principal userPrincipal = externalContext.getUserPrincipal();
    if (userPrincipal == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return userPrincipal.getName();
}

public boolean userLogged() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    Principal principal = externalContext.getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void efetuarLogout() throws IOException, ServletException {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
    request.logout();
    ec.redirect(ec.getApplicationContextPath());
}

public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    return externalContext.isUserInRole(role);
}

public void remove(Usuario entidade) {
    getService().remove(entidade);
    limpar();
}

public Usuario getEntidade() {
    return entidade;
}

public void setEntidade(Usuario entidade) {
    this.entidade = entidade;
}

public Collection<Usuario> getEntidades() {
    return entidades;
}

public void setEntidades(Collection<Usuario> entidades) {
    this.entidades = entidades;
}

public void save() {
    getService().save(entidade);
    limpar();
}


public void limpar() {
    entidades = getService().getAll();
    entidade = new Usuario();
}


public UserService getService() {
    return service;
}

public String getAutPassword() {
    return autPassword;
}

public void setAutPassword(String autPassword) {
    this.autPassword = autPassword;
}
```

}

Comment: Sempre que pedir ajuda para resolução de erros desse tipo, adicione o stack trace do erro para facilitar você a receber ajuda na análise do seu problema.